# TinyMCE: Possible to limit to only allow bullets?

Tags: tinymce

I'd like, if possible, to use TinyMCE (WYSIWYG Editor) to allow users to created bulleted lists *and only* bulleted lists. Anyone know of a way?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 5):

TinyMCE has two options that will help, when using the advanced theme.  The first is [`theme_advanced_buttons<n>`](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/theme_advanced_buttons_1_n), which determines which buttons are shown with the editor.  Since the advanced theme by default defines buttons in three rows, you'll need to redefine each one.

The second is [`valid_elements`](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/valid_elements), which lets TinyMCE remove any unlisted tags.  It can also transform one tag into another; for example, you might wish to switch numbered lists into bulleted lists.  Note, however, that this isn't really security; you still need to perform server-side checks to block invalid input from malicious or devious users.

If you really want to block all tags except bulleted lists, your init call might want the following options:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // Select the advanced theme
    theme : "advanced",

    // Choose which buttons to show
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bullist",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",

    // Which html tags to allow
    valid_elements : "-ul/-ol,-li",

    // Other options, including what to make editable
    mode : ...
});
```

If, on the other hand, you only want to prevent numbered lists, your configuration might look more like:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // Select the advanced theme
    theme : "advanced",

    // Choose which buttons to show
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "separator,insertdate,inserttime,preview,zoom,separator,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bullist,separator,outdent,indent,separator,undo,redo,separator",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "hr,removeformat,visualaid,separator,sub,sup,separator,charmap",

    // Which html tags to allow
    valid_elements : "@[id|class|style|title|dir<ltr?rtl|lang|xml::lang|onclick|ondblclick|" +
        "onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseover|onmousemove|onmouseout|onkeypress|" +
        "onkeydown|onkeyup],a[rel|rev|charset|hreflang|tabindex|accesskey|type|" +
        "name|href|target|title|class|onfocus|onblur],strong/b,em/i,strike,u," +
        "#p[align],-ul[type|compact]/-ol[type|compact],-li,br,img[longdesc|usemap|" +
        "src|border|alt=|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align],-sub,-sup," +
        "-blockquote,-table[border=0|cellspacing|cellpadding|width|frame|rules|" +
        "height|align|summary|bgcolor|background|bordercolor],-tr[rowspan|width|" +
        "height|align|valign|bgcolor|background|bordercolor],tbody,thead,tfoot," +
        "#td[colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|bgcolor|background|bordercolor" +
        "|scope],#th[colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|scope],caption,-div," +
        "-span,-code,-pre,address,-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-h6,hr[size|noshade],-font[face" +
        "|size|color],dd,dl,dt,cite,abbr,acronym,del[datetime|cite],ins[datetime|cite]," +
        "object[classid|width|height|codebase|*],param[name|value|_value],embed[type|width" +
        "|height|src|*],script[src|type],map[name],area[shape|coords|href|alt|target],bdo," +
        "button,col[align|char|charoff|span|valign|width],colgroup[align|char|charoff|span|" +
        "valign|width],dfn,fieldset,form[action|accept|accept-charset|enctype|method]," +
        "input[accept|alt|checked|disabled|maxlength|name|readonly|size|src|type|value]," +
        "kbd,label[for],legend,noscript,optgroup[label|disabled],option[disabled|label|selected|value]," +
        "q[cite],samp,select[disabled|multiple|name|size],small," +
        "textarea[cols|rows|disabled|name|readonly],tt,var,big",


    // Other options, including what to make editable
    mode : ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your tinyMCE.init set the theme-advanced-buttons1 to just have "bullist".  **You'll also need to set theme-advanced-buttons2, 3, and 4 to nothing.**  Here's a full example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Application Name</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({
            // General options
            mode : "exact",
            elements: "description_edit_box",
            theme : "advanced",
            plugins : "safari,pagebreak,inlinepopups,paste,searchreplace",

            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bullist",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,

            // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
            external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js"
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<textarea id="description_edit_box" rows="5" ></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```